# Is it good to create new object if pointer is null just to get its fields or not?

Tags: java, option-type, nullable, null-safety

Is it good to write like this?

```
UserInfo myMethod(User user) {
    user = Optional.ofNullable(user).orElse(new User())?

    String name = user.getName()
    String type = user.getType();

    return new UserInfo(name, type);
}
```

Or better use standard way:

```
UserInfo myMethod(User user) {
    if(user == null) { return null }
    
    String name = user.getName()
    String type = user.getType();

    return new UserInfo(name, type);
}
```

Could also someone help with good null safety best practice links?

Comment: It depends on why `user` is allowed to be null in the first place.

Comment: One important part of handling `null` is to **define** what happens when you pass `null` to it. A straightforward one is to straight up forbidd it (and throw an exception if it happens anyway). And as long as your project has a good general guideline in this regard (for example "null values are not allowed as parameters except in exceptionas A, B and C and those need to be indicated using X, Y and Z" you don't even always need to read that documentation to know how `null` is handled.

Comment: You could make a new constructor for UserInfo that takes a User object, which might be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version looks pretty much a code smell: you return a `UserInfo` object corresponding to a null `User`. This seems like a counter-intuitive approach, and can lead to all sorts of validation problems if the fields `name` and `type` are unspecified. The second version is better because it just returns null if the user is null. Another approach is to enforce the caller to pass a non-null argument using:

```
UserInfo myMethod(User user) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(user);
    ...
}
```